# mysql group by summarized column

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have worked around with this query:

```
SELECT round(avg(total_kpi),2) as avg_kpi, 
case when avg(total_kpi) < 3 then 'NEG' 
     when avg(total_kpi)>3 then 'POS' end  as kpi, 
count(gender) as gender,  
gender,  
round(avg(locacion),2) as avg_locacion, 
round(avg(tiempo),2) as avg_tiempo, 
round(avg(servicio),2) as avg_servicio, 
round(avg(calidad),2) as avg_calidad 
FROM datellig_ift.a02_view_kpi_2 
WHERE id_man_medicion=4 
group by 
case when avg(total_kpi) < 3 then 'NEG' 
     when avg(total_kpi) > 3 then 'POS' end
```

I need to group data by column 2.  When grouping by,  mysql rejects.
Sorry,  I've been looking some posts but don't understand why is not working.
Thanks.

Error message:

> #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Comment: thanks,  #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Comment: consider using having clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AVG()` cannot be in your `GROUP BY` clause, as it is a "Group By" or "Aggregate" function.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html for details of all the aggregate functions.

Based on your follow up, I'm guessing this query will suit you:

```
SELECT
    IF(total_kpi < 3, 'NEG', 'POS') AS type,
    gender,  
    count(*) AS members,  
    round(avg(total_kpi),2) as avg_kpi, 
    round(avg(locacion),2) as avg_locacion, 
    round(avg(tiempo),2) as avg_tiempo, 
    round(avg(servicio),2) as avg_servicio, 
    round(avg(calidad),2) as avg_calidad 
FROM
    datellig_ift.a02_view_kpi_2 
WHERE
   id_man_medicion = 4 
GROUP BY
    total_kpi < 3, 
    gender
```

Comment: Thanks,  how can I replace AVG(),  in order to get less granularity.

Comment: We will need more information to be able to answer that with any certainly.

Comment: Basically you just need to group by something else which makes more sense.

Comment: My specific need is to deploy data that shows me, based on users qualification of service,  the following tree: how many persons assigned positive 'POS', how many negative 'NEG',  and from each NEG and POS,  haw many where women 'FEM' and how many men 'MASC'.  I have the numeric values of each qualification,  so using case-when I can separate NEG from POS.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow, but if `total_kpi < 3` is NEG and `total_kpi >= 3` is POS, then to create a NEG bucket and a POS bucket use: `group by total_kpi < 3`

Comment: HI,  lasta night I finally found a solution.  Due to my low rating,  were not allowed to answer my question.  However Ross Smith II helped me,  and checking his proposed solution I found it also works fine.  Here is what I did:

Answer (score 0):

last night I finally found a solution.  Due to my low rating,  were not allowed to answer my question.  However Ross Smith II helped me,  and checking his proposed solution I found it also works fine.  Here is what I did:

```
SELECT count(total_kpi) as q_kpi, 
case when total_kpi < 3 then  'NEG'  when total_kpi>3 then  'POS'  end  as kpi, 
count(gender) as gender, 
gender, 
round(avg(locacion),2) as avg_locacion, 
round(avg(tiempo),2) as avg_tiempo, 
round(avg(servicio),2) as avg_servicio,
round(avg(calidad),2) as avg_calidad 
FROM datellig_ift.a02_view_kpi_2  where id_man_medicion=4 GROUP BY 2, 4
```

Thanks Ross Smith your comments leaded to finding the answer.

Comment: What about when `total_kpi` equals exactly 3? `IF(total_kpi < 3, 'NEG', 'POS') AS kpi` is shorter, and cleaner than the `CASE` statement you are using.

Comment: Yes indeed I changed my case statement to your proposed IF().  Is better and indeed it solved the equal to 3 issue, which by the away I hadn't noticed.  Thanks, excellent advisory.